# Lista de atributos do Entity Framework para mapeamento de entidades

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Por meu *Database* estar fora da convenção do EF, e como outro sistema já desenvolvido usa ele, fica fora de cogitação mudar nomes de tabelas/colunas.

Gostaria de saber os atributos disponíveis (ex: `[Key]`, `[ForeignKey]`) para "driblar" possíveis problemas que venham a ocorrer.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx

Comment: Eu ia colocar numa resposta, mas tenho certeza que o Cigano já deve estar terminando uma :p

Comment: Estou. Aguardem.

Comment: Sensacional galera! Porque não descobri essa comunidade antes?! haha

Comment: Seja bem-vindo e faça bom proveito =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A maioria dos atributos está aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) e [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema(v=vs.110).aspx), mas vou fazer um guia rápido que pode ser útil para a sua conversão.

## Atributos de campos (propriedades)

### [`[Key]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Especifica quando uma propriedade é ou faz parte de uma chave. Pode ser usado em mais de um parâmetro.

Possui ainda um parâmetro chamado [`Column`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx), em que é possível especificar a ordem de cada chave.

### [`[Column]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Especifica o nome da coluna quando ela é diferente do nome da propriedade.

### [`[ForeignKey]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Especifica qual propriedade representa ligação de chave estrangeira em um *Model*. Pode ser usado em dois casos:

- Em uma propriedade de dados, para especificar qual propriedade de navegação se refere:

  ```
  [ForeignKey("MinhaPropriedadeDeNavegacao")]
  public int MinhaChaveEstrangeira { get; set; }

  public virtual TabelaEstrangeira MinhaPropriedadeDeNavegacao { get; set; }
  ```
- Em uma propriedade de navegação, para especificar qual propriedade de dados se refere:

  ```
  public int MinhaChaveEstrangeira { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("MinhaChaveEstrangeira")]
  public virtual TabelaEstrangeira MinhaPropriedadeDeNavegacao { get; set; }
  ```

### [`[InverseProperty]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Desfaz ambiguidades quando uma tabela tem relações múltiplas 1 para N para outra tabela.

```
    public class Orientador
    {
        public int OrientadorId { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("OrientadorAntigo")]
        public virtual ICollection<Aluno> AlunosAntigos { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("OrientadorNovo")]
        public virtual ICollection<Aluno> AlunosNovos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Aluno
    {
        public int AlunoId { get; set; }
        public int OrientadorAntigoId { get; set; }
        public int OrientadorNovoId { get; set; }

        public virtual Orientador OrientadorAntigo { get; set; }
        public virtual Orientador OrientadorNovo { get; set; }
    }
```

### [`[NotMapped]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Indica ao Entity Framework que determinada propriedade não existe em banco. Pode ser um campo auxiliar que só apareça em tela ou que seja usado para alguma funçaõ em *Controller*.

### [`[DatabaseGenerated]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Indica que o campo não será preenchido na aplicação, e sim, no banco de dados, por alguma regra específica.

[Aceita como parâmetro uma enumeração](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx), que possui os seguintes valores:

- `Identity`: geração sequencial feita pelo banco;
- `None`: não é gerada pelo banco, explicitamente;
- `Computed`: geração por algum cálculo de banco de dados, como uma *Trigger* de inserção, por exemplo.

## Atributos de classes

### [`[Table]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Especifica o nome da tabela, caso ele seja diferente do nome da classe do *Model*.

> Pretendo enriquecer esta resposta conforme forem aparecendo dúvidas e necessidade de exemplos, mas é um bom ponto de partida.

Comment: E se eu quiser um campo especifico de outra classe com um nome diferente? Por ex:

public partial class Usuario 
{
 public int id{ get; set; }
 public string nome { get; set; }
 public bool ativo { get; set; }
[Essa propriedade vem de outro modelo "Nivel" e seu nome é "nome"]
 public string NivelNome { get; set; }

Comment: Aí sua modelagem está incorreta, porque propriedades de outras classes devem ficar em outras classes.

Comment: Então nao existe a possibilidade de colocar campos de outra tabela (niveis) diretamente no modelo de usuarios? Como no exemplo citado, o nome do nivel direto no modelo de usuario?

Comment: Não existe. Você pode, ao invés disso, referenciar a outra classe. O Entity Framework carrega ela sozinho pra você.