# Entidade com múltiplos membros do mesmo tipo no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Quando temos duas entidades relacionadas many-to-many e criamos as propriedades de navegação de forma correta o entity cria uma tabela extra para configurar esse relacionamento.

No caso em que estou trabalhando tenho uma estrutura que no melhor dos mundos seria parecido com isso:

```
public class User {
    public string Name {get;set}
    public int id
}

public class Forum {
    public string Title {get;set}
    public virtual ICollection<User> Participants {get;set}
    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers {get;set}
}
```

O problema aqui ocorre justamente por ter duas propriedades do tipo User. O entity vai tentar guardar tudo na mesma tabela, e vai criar duas chaves estrangeiras no User.

Qual é a boa prática nesse caso? Seria criar duas entidades diferentes (Participants e Followers) e guardar os ids do User e do Forum em cada uma delas?

Comment: Antes de mais nada, cuidado com palavras restritas, "User" por exemplo costuma a dar erro pois é usada internamente pelo EF se não me engano. Procure ser o mais específico, use SeuSistemaUser.
No seu caso, tanto 'Participants' quanto 'Followers' são do tipo 'User', logo eu pergunto, como saber quem é quem?
Ao meu ver você tem duas opções, criar especializações para que 'Participant' e 'Followers' herdem 'User'. Ou criar uma nova propriedade em 'User' para guardar o tipo de usuário, um Enum do tipo 'UserType' já serveria, onde você aponta se é 'Participant' ou 'Follower'.

Comment: @StefanoSandes  , está utilizando code first?

Comment: Sim @Vinícius, code first.

Comment: @petersonfortes entendi a sua ideia. A questão é, tratando-se de orientação à objetos duas coleções do mesmo tipo se distinguem de forma fácil, mas no BD, como ajustar o entity para mapear isso para duas tabelas? Eu posso criar duas classes especializadas como você disse sim, mas me parece que estaria pensando de forma relcional, e não OO. Quanto a tipar, não faria sentido em uma aplicação grande onde as referencias podem estar em muitas entidades. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Stefano Sandes até onde percebo orientação a objeto em banco de dados é mito, a ideia é bem antiga, mas na prática não existe. Infelizmente o Entity Framework não consegue magicamente resolver este tipo de coisa para você, a solução é alterar o seu EDMX na mão, mesmo assim isso é um porre porque sempre que houver alteração no banco e você tiver que atualizar seu EDMX, você terá que refazer estas alterações manuais. Usar alguma lógica em sua camada de negócio na minha opinião é a melhor solução, para este caso.

Comment: Entendi @petersonfortes. Tinha esperança de haver uma forma de configurá-lo para isso. Já trabalhei com database-first e conseguia fazer o NHibernate entender esse tipo de relacionamento. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Stefano Sandes atualmente estou trabalhando com NHibernate também e é lindo. Não sinto saudades nenhuma do EF.

Answer (score 3):

> Qual é a boa prática nesse caso?

Depende do que você precisa. Se você precisa que os dados estejam unificados, a abordagem está correta. Se isto não é necessário, é pertinente separar.

Em caso de estrutura unificada, atualize para o seguinte:

```
public class User 
{
    public int id
    public int? ForumParticipantId { get; set; }
    public int? ForumFollowerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Forum ForumParticipant { get; set; }
    public virtual Forum ForumFollower { get; set; }
}

public class Forum 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ForumParticipant")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Participants { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ForumFollower")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
}
```

[Veja mais sobre o `[InverseProperty]` aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93277/lista-de-atributos-do-entity-framework-para-mapeamento-de-entidades/93286#93286).

Comment: Entendi. O que me incomoda um pouco nessa abordagem é o fato de as entidades ficarem infladas de propriedades que no final acabam servindo apenas pra ensinar o entity o que fazer. Numa aplicação de médio porte, imagina em quantas entidade User pode ser referido.. No final a classe de User terminaria com trocentas propriedades. Foi isso que eu quis dizer com "boa prática". Esse é mesmo o melhor cenário? Talvez num caso como esse fosse melhor abrir da prop de navegação.  Muito obrigado Cigano!

Comment: É só a gente se colocar no lugar do desenvolvedor do framework: já pensou na dificudade de colocar toda essa inteligência nele? Apesar da decoração, tudo funciona.

Comment: Concordo que deve ter um nível de dificuldade grande, mas discordo sobre me colocar no lugar "do desenvolvedor". Se eu for partir desse pressuposto, nada faz nada que seja muito difícil. De qualquer forma, não é uma exigência sobre o que o framework deveria ter ou não, pelo contrário, é uma dúvida sobre qual seria a boa prática para casos como esse. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela ajuda.